# What options are available with Facebooks data-perms?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to link our produce in with the Facebook Login plugin. It mentions the data-perms attribute to get data about the user, for our own use (i.e. so we can create a user account in our database. I know, obviously, we can't get the password, but I am wondering what attributes we do have access to. Currently the only ones I can find are email and user_checkins. Does anyone know what the other options are? I've Googled it for a while but I can't find any kind of definitive list or anything. The only documentation I have found is http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login, which only mentions the above two fields.

Also how do you access the information after they've logged in? I am still researching this but if anyone can post a quick answer about this I'd much appreciate it.

Edit: Just found an apparently definitive list of available data: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Regards,
Richard

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ lists the different permissions and breaks them into categories too

Answer (score 0):

When fetching data about a user from Facebook you either use Graph API or FQL, Graph API is the simpler one of those two.

To explore the Graph API you can use [Facebook's Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=589575776). Clicking on the "Get Access Token" button in the explorer shows you all the different "special permissions" available.

You can find the documentation over the different features of the Facebook Graph and how to work server to server with Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

If you are more interested in fetching the info from client side you should look at the [JavaScript SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

In order to access the data about the user after they have logged in you can simply do an API call to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=THETOKENYOUGOTFROMFACEBOOK

That will retrieve the info about the user which  the token belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using OAuth 2.0, it's advised to use the new implementation as soon as possible. And if you do so, you should replace `data-perms` with `data-scope` and the list of "permissions" available can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Also it seems that you are a bit confused here, this field means that the user grant your app a permission to access such data...it doesn't mean that the login plugin will return it!
For instance, you don't provide `name` or `first_name` as these data will be provided once a user allow your app (even without any permission).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - particularly the 2nd bit. Yes I may have been a bit confused, but it looks like the other answer will enable me to get the info I want. Basically our client has requested to integrate the Facebook Login button with our standard Login form, so users can login or, if they don't have an account on our server, create an account using only the most basic information from Facebook - email, firstname, surname and possibly other details. We'd assign them a random password but so long as they're logged in to Facebook it will bypass the password if a certain column...

Comment: ...contains their FB user ID. We'd get the userID at registration, alongside the email etc, and put it in a certain column so that we can relate that FB userID to the unique ID of that row in the users table. Note that the random password is just for security purposes - to stop users logging into accounts without a password.

Comment: Be aware! it's a bit more tricky...what if an existing user tried to login through Facebook where he used a different e-mail? or chosed not to share his email with you (Facebook will return a proxied e-mail in this case)? you'll have two different accounts for the same user! Best thing to do is to ask the FB user after login if he has an existing account to put that account's username/email and password and do the linking.